# Using array as `this.state` I'm getting map() is not a function errors

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I don't know why but I have an "is not a function" error in my React `class` component. I want to increase the the count of a product in React with context.

I created context and used my context in `main.jsx` and gave the main component state and some functions. I can use states but I can't use functions in the context.

Main file - here's the state array:

```
state = [
    {prodoctName : "food" , count : 0, id:0},
    {prodoctName : "water" , count : 0, id:1},
    {prodoctName : "store" , count : 0, id:2},
    {prodoctName : "game" , count : 0, id:3},
    {prodoctName : "how" , count : 0, id:4}
];
```

Here's where I use the state to create the context:

```
increase = (id = 0)=>{
    let newState = [...this.state];
    newState[id].count += 1;
    this.setState(newState);
}

render() {
    return (
        <>
        <MyContext.Provider
            value={{
                increase : this.increase,
                reduce : this.reduce,
                sumCount : this.sumCount,
                state : this.state,
            }}>
        <Products></Products> 
        </MyContext.Provider>
        </>
    );
}
```

Products file (this is where I have the error):

```
class Products extends Component {
    static contextType = MyContext;
    render() {
        return (
            <>
                {this.context.state.map((p)=>{
                    return <Product key={p.id} ProductId={p.id}></Product>
                })}
            </>
        );
    }
}
```

Product file:

```
class Product extends Component{
    static contextType = MyContext;
    render() {
        return (
             <div>
                <span>{this.context.state[this.props.ProductId].prodoctName}</span>
                <span> {this.context.state[this.props.ProductId].count} </span>
                <button onClick={()=>{this.context.increase(this.props.ProductId)}}>+</button>
             </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Why am I getting that error?

Comment: The unique thing about this question vs. all the other "map is not a function" questions is that the OP is trying to use an array as the `state` member of a React `class` component. This sets up the non-obvious situation where `setState(newArray)` triggers the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `class`-based components, your state object can't be an array object, it has to be a simple object. That's because when you call `setState`, React merges the previous state and the state object you give it together into a plain object on the `state` property. So although your code would work initially, the first time you call `setState` your `state` property becomes a non-Array object.

Instead, make your state an object with a property that contains the array you want:

```
state = {
    items: [
        // ...
    ]
};
```

...and adjust the code to use `this.state.items` instead of `this.state` to access the array. For instance, in the main file code you've shown:

```
increase = (id = 0) => {
    this.setState(({items}) => {            // ***
        const newItems = [...items];        // ***
        newItems[id].count += 1;            // ***
        return { items };                   // ***
    });                                     // ***
};

render() {
    return (
        <>
        <MyContext.Provider
            value={{
                increase : this.increase,
                reduce : this.reduce,
                sumCount : this.sumCount,
                state : this.state.items,   // ***
            }}>
        <Products></Products> 
        </MyContext.Provider>
        </>
    );
}
```

Aside from the change to keep the array in `this.state.items` instead of directly in `this.state`, note that in `increase` I updated the code to use the callback form of `setState`. You should do that whenever you're updating state based on existing state, because state updates can be asynchronous and queued up, so when you call `setState` the `this.state` value may be stale.

(You might also consider changing the `state` property in your context to be `items` or something else that more clearly expresses what the contents of the array are.)

---

Side note: `class` components are now [a legacy API](https://react.dev/reference/react/legacy#legacy-apis). I doubt it's going away any time soon, but you might consider switching to function components with hooks when you can. (Maybe you already know that, most of us have legacy code we have to maintain and can only evolve over time, but just in case...)

Comment: @ArshiaCode - Glad that helped! Since you're new here, I'll point to [what to do when someone answers](/help/someone-answers). Happy coding! I remember being a 15 year-old boy programming. In my case, the computer only had 1k of memory (the big one I could rent time on had 8k!), but it's the same thing... :-D